# Creating a Cylinder Class

Tags: java

I'm currently undertaking a Java class (one of my final ones for my bachelor, yay) and I'm having a really difficult time trying to understand classes and do this problem below. The textbook I'm currently using is quite confusing and I've tried to use other online resources to figure out what I'm doing wrong but I still seem stuck on the question below. Whenever I try and run the program all I get is `0.00.0` for my answer, is this due to myself incorrectly assigning values to `cylinder1`? Also, for the `toString()` class how do I even go about doing this? I'm always getting errors on converting `double`s to `String`s no matter what I can do.

Any help would be appreciated it.

Thanks.

## Prompt

> Implement the class called `Cylinder` shown in UML below. The constructor accepts and initializes the radius and height for the `Cylinder`, while accessors and mutators allow them to be changed after object construction. The class also include methods that calculate and return the volume and surface area of the `Cylinder`. Lastly, it contains a `toString` method that returns the name of the shape, its radius, and its height. Create a `main` method which instantiates 4 `Cylinder` objects (any parameters), display them with `toString()`, change one parameter (your choice) in each, and display them again. [15 points]

## UML

[image: uml]

## Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Cylinder
{
    private double radius, height, area, volume;

    public Cylinder(double height, double radius) {
        radius = 0.0;
        height = 0.0;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        double area = (2 * Math.PI * radius * height) + (2 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2));
        return area;
    }

    public void setRadius(double r) {
        radius = r;
    }

    public void setHeight(double h) {
        height = h;
    }

    public double calcVolume() {
        double volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * height;
        return volume;
    }

    public String toString (){
        StringBuilder StBuild = new StringBuilder();
        StBuild.append(radius).append(height);
        return StBuild.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(5, 5);
        System.out.println(cylinder1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the constructor you set both values to 0.0

Answer (score 3):

Since this is obviously homework I won't give you the answers, but I'll try to explain a few things.

This:

```
public Cylinder(double height, double radius) {
  radius = 0.0;
  height = 0.0;
}
```

is a constructor. When you create an object (and instance of a class)  you call this. You call it by doing:

```
Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(5, 5);
```

But what happens in your class? When you call the constructor are you really saving the values you want?

As for the toString method, you could either call the toString for the double (height.toString) or you could just do what I always end up doing which is just cheat by adding a string to it.

```
public String toString (){
return "Cylinder [ h: " + height + " - r: " + radius + " - v: " + calcValume() + "]";
}
```

Comment: Remember to add the name of the Shape in the toString method.

Comment: You're right. I expanded the toString a little, but he should get the idea and be able to get it how he wants it.

Answer (score 1):

in class `Cylinder` change the constructor to:

```
public Cylinder(double height, double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.height = height;
}
```

In void main() :

```
Cylinder cylinder1 = new Cylinder(5, 5);
System.out.println(cylinder1.calcVolume());
```

This will work.

But you should shift the main method to some other class.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you are setting the radius and height to 0.0. Try:

```
public Cylinder(double height, double radius) {
    this.radius = radius.
    this.height = height;
}
```